# HelixToolkit change BillboardTextVisual3D origin

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

Normally when we create a BillboardTextVisual3D it's origin is in its center. Is there any way to change this? The position is defined in world coordinates and I would like to offset the billboard in screen coordinates.

To be more exactly I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

I have the world position of the red dot, which is the position that I'm using to draw the green target billboard. I would like to show a text below it with its coordinates (blue billboard), which would be another billboard that should be positioned right below the green one.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: why can't you do: newCenter = redDot.Center - offsetVector ?

Comment: Because the coordinates are passed in world coordinates and my offset is in screen coordinates.